# number of non-zero, distinct, eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V^T$ denote the transpose of a vector $V$. Consider two non-zero $p$-dimensional column vectors $a$ and $b$, for $p\ge 2$.

How many non-zero distinct eigen-values does the $p\times p$ matrix $ab^T + b a^T$ have?

Comment: For the formatting of formulas, please have a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging $(ab^T+ba^T)v$, where $v$ is an eigenvector, we get:

$$\begin{align}
ab^Tv+ba^Tv &= a(b^Tv)+b(a^Tv) \\
 &= a\langle b,v\rangle + b\langle a,v\rangle \\
 &= \lambda v
\end{align}$$

Which means that $v$ is of the form $v = v_aa + v_bb$. Now substitute that back into the previous equation. To get the eigenvalues, we need to solve:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle a,b\rangle && \|b\|^2 \\
\|a\|^2 && \langle a,b\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} v_a \\ v_b \end{bmatrix}
=
\lambda\begin{bmatrix} v_a \\ v_b \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\begin{align}
&\Rightarrow \left(\langle a,b\rangle - \lambda\right)^2 = \|a\|^2\|b\|^2 \\
&\Rightarrow \lambda = \langle a,b\rangle \pm\|a\|\|b\|
\end{align}$$

That gives $2$ eigenvalues, unless $a$ and $b$ are parallel, in which case one of the $\lambda$ above will be zero.